# Kubernetes Pod mount /var/run/docker.sock and use imagePullSecrets

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-registry

I assign an `imagePullSecrets` to my pod which allows the pod(?) to pull an image for a container from a private registry:

```
spec:
  imagePullSecrets:
  - name: dockerrep
```

This works great. Now in my pod spec I do pass the docker instance down with:

```
spec:
  volumes:
  - name: dockersock
    hostPath:
      path: /var/run/docker.sock
```

This way I can use docker inside my container! (I also mount it inside the container). But inside my container the docker instance is not allowed to pull using the `imagePullSecrets` provided to the pod itself.

Does anyone know if there is a direct way to do this? I thought that the docker instance (that's "passed down") into the container would automatically inherit the "docker login" from the `imagePullSecret`.

I know I can mount the pull secret manually again inside my container and perform a "docker login", just wanting to know if there is a direct way.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the imagepullsecrets assigned to a service account a la https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/#add-imagepullsecrets-to-a-service-account?

Comment: Yes, I tried assigned to service account or directly to pod spec.

Comment: Did you try securityContext: runasuser, fsgroup? Could you please provide full deployment yaml, and logs?

Comment: I'm trying to do same thing and facing a lot of problems with it.. did you manage to make it work ?

Comment: @nabeel I couldn't get it to work, I had to mount the secret again manually inside the container.

Comment: I did try that before, and i needed to perform AWS login manually  and that was problematic.. did it work after mounting the secret without any login ? in case you have a solution can you please post it. thanks

Comment: will it still be possible to mount docker.sock and run docker in kubernets with the deprecation of docker in kubernetes?